# How to call the icon theme for an icon

Tags: flutter

In flutter the `MaterialApp` widget has a `theme` property where you can set fonts, background colors etc... When I need a text theme for example, using the `style` property, I can set the theme with `Theme.of(context).textTheme.title)` . How would I do similar with setting the theme for `icons`. Icons doesn't have a style property.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IconTheme` class.

```
new IconTheme(
  data: new IconThemeData(
      color: Colors.blue), 
  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `icons` you want to style with `IconButton` widget which has `color:` property, but you should disable it to hide the effect of user clicks , or you can set the highlighting color to `Colors.transparent`